# Two child processes create 3 child process each

Tags: linux, unix, process, fork

I'm struggling with making a C program, where the parent process creates 2 child processes, and those 2 childs create 3 child process on their own. I get the 6 child-child processes as outcome, but 2 of the 6 is the child of the parent. I can't seem to make this work. 
Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
pid_t pid[2];
pid_t pid2[3];

for (i=0;i<2;i++) {
    pid[i] = fork();
    if (pid[i] == 0) {
        break;
    }
}

if (pid[0] != 0 && pid[1] != 0) {
    // That's the father, it waits for all the childs
    printf("The parent process [pid: %d, ppid: %d]\n",getpid(),getppid());
    for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
        wait(&tmp);
    }
} else {
    printf("I'm a child process [pid: %d, ppid: %d]\n",getpid(),getppid());
    for (k=0; k<3; k++){
    pid2[k]=fork();
    if (pid2[k]==0){
    break;
    }

    }

    if (pid2[0] == 0 && pid2[1] == 0 && pid2[2] == 0){
    }
    else{
    printf("Child of child [pid: %d, ppid: %d]\n",getpid(),getppid());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `pid2[k]` is 0 for any k, it is a grandchild.
So it only is a the first level child, when all pid2's are positive:

```
/* correct code */
    if (pid2[0] > 0 && pid2[1] > 0 && pid2[2] > 0){
       printf("I am a child with 3 children\n");
    }
    else{
       printf("Child of child [pid: %d, ppid: %d]\n",getpid(),getppid());
    }
```

What you wrote will happen only once for each first level child: The first grandchild `k=0` will have `pid2[0]==0`, and will not update `pid2[1]` and `pid2[2]`, these can be random or 0, depending on your compiler.
The other grand children will have the pid of their oldest brother in `pid2[0]`.

```
/* incorrect code with additional printf */
    if (pid2[0] == 0 && pid2[1] == 0 && pid2[2] == 0){
       printf("I am one of the oldest children\n");
    }
    else {
       printf("Child or Younger Child of child [pid: %d, ppid: %d]\n",getpid(),getppid());
    }
```

Now you should aldo handle situations where the `fork()` fails (`pid< 0`).

Comment: Got it working! Thanks for your help I appreciate it!

Comment: ok. Now you can try to build a family tree known to all processes, using getppid(), and some inter process communication or `popen("/bin/ps -ef", "r");` I don't like the variables `pid#[]` that have a different meaning in different processes. Or do what you wanted of course.